# Display Language specific content

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I created two languages

English and French

I am facing problem when content is not translated into french by default its displaying english content.

How to display only french content if i select french language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/select_translation

Install the module and Add filter in view by selecting(content translation:select translation) field

And select this option : use current language ; if not available use original language